# How to parse string pattern in php while the string is complex

Tags: php, string, parsing, delimiter

i need your help about how to parse the string. I have a string with structure below :

MALANG|TVhHMTAwMDBK MALANGBONG,GARUT|QkRPMjA3MTlK MALANGKE BARAT,MASAMBA|VVBHMjMzMDVK MALANGKE,MASAMBA|VVBHMjMzMDRK

I'm now confuse how to parse this string so that i can get a pattern like this :

```
MALANG|TVhHMTAwMDBK
MALANGBONG,GARUT|QkRPMjA3MTlK
MALANGKE BARAT,MASAMBA|VVBHMjMzMDVK
MALANGKE BARAT,MASAMBA|VVBHMjMzMDVK
```

The pattern output are City_Name|RandomCode

I have try to use explode by space, but the city name sometimes also contains a space. What function in php i could use to solve this problem?

Comment: Do they all start with MALAN... or is there any other possibility?

Comment: As it has no structure (the random bit is a give away) go and ask the data provider to give you more details

Comment: hi Kuzgun, The word MALAN will be replaced with some variabel. Such as replaced with SUR :
SURABAYA|axasdasWsdzx SURABAYA, BARAT DAYA|tverWasfxGMH and etc.
Or may be raplaced with the other word that look like similar as city name in my country, such as JAKA :
JAKARTA|nmTRGBSjgWVB JAKARTA BARAT,TANGERANG|kmliHYDgDjgg

Comment: Are all the random code parts 12 characters long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one out. It fits your example ok

```
$str = 'MALANG|TVhHMTAwMDBK MALANGBONG,GARUT|QkRPMjA3MTlK MALANGKE BARAT,MASAMBA|VVBHMjMzMDVK MALANGKE,MASAMBA|VVBHMjMzMDRK';
$pattern = '/(?<=^| )[A-Z, ]+?\|[A-Za-z0-9]+(?= |$)/';

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches)) {
    $parts = $matches[0];
}
```

You may need to tweak some of the character classes if say your city names contain anything other than capital letters, spaces and commas.

Example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/6ujl3p

Alternatively, if the *RandomCode* parts are guaranteed to all be 12 characters long, `preg_split` may be a better fit, eg

```
$pattern = '/(?<=\|[A-Za-z0-9]{12}) /';
$parts = preg_split($pattern, $str);
```

Demo here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wd4Wmc

Comment: Thankyou @Phil, it work now.
    $pattern = '/(?<=^| )[A-Z, ]+?\|[A-Za-z0-9]+(?= |$)/';
Is it means that $pattern will check every string before | and every string after | limited by space ? 
Yes, this is what i means, i need more time to learn and understand about string pattern and string manipulation. Thanks for your help every body ;)

Comment: @ParminSupaidiST See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for more information